# How do I configure Content Security Policy for base64 images?

Tags: media

I'm using the [Content Security Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp) module and I placed restrictions on **img-src**.

Set to `Self`.

**Additional sources**:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.gstatic.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googletagmanager.com
```

However, my logs are filled with messages like this:

> [Report Only] Refused to load the image
> 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAD1JREFUeNpiYGBgOADE%2F3Hgw0DM4IRHgSsDFOzFInmMAQnY49ONzZRjDFiADT7dMLALiE8y4AGW6LoBAgwAuIkf%2F%2FB7O9sAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com
> https://ssl.gstatic.com https://www.gstatic.com
> https://www.googletagmanager.com".

How do I allow the base64 images provided by Drupal (jsonapi in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449556/1209486), you need to add `data:` to **Additional Sources**:

```
data: https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.gstatic.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googletagmanager.com
```